# How to select a list where one property is not in a list of integers?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have the following lists

```
List<int> toExclude = new List<int>(); //Assume I have number between 1-10

List<ReportObjectRelation> relations = new List<ReportObjectRelation>(); //Assume I have multiple `ReportObjectRelation` objects in this list
```

I need to pull the list of `relations` where `CurrentObjectId = 6` and `RemoteObjectId` is not in the `toExclude` list.

Here is my `ReportObjectRelation` object

```
public class ReportObjectRelation
{
    //Relation
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    //Local Object
    public int CurrentObjectId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentObjectName { get; set; }
    public int ForeignPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string ForeignProperty { get; set; }

    //Remote Object
    public int RemoteObjectId { get; set; }
    public string RemoteObjectName { get; set; }
    public int LocalPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string RemoteProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I tried

```
var f = allRelations.Where(x => x.CurrentObjectId == 6 && !toExceule.Exists(x.RemoteObjectId) ).ToList();
```

but this is giving me the following error

Cannot use ref out parameter `toExceule` an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression.

How can I correctly pull a list of relations where `CurrentObjectId == 6` and `RemoteObjectId` is not in `toExceule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an out parameter inside an anonymous method. You need to assign it first to a local variable. (I don't really know why you're using an output parameter in this case because you didn't show you whole code):

```
var copyOfList = toExceule;
var f = allRelations.Where(x => x.CurrentObjectId == 6 
                             && !copyOfList .Contains(x.RemoteObjectId)).ToList();
```

If you want to use Exists, you can try something like this:

```
var f = allRelations.Where(x => x.CurrentObjectId == 6 
                             && !copyOfList.Exists(y=> y == x.RemoteObjectId)).ToList();
```

This trick is purely because the lambda expressions change the life-time of the local variables.

Comment: @Jaylen check the edit. You need to assign a copy of the out parameter. I don't know why you're using a output parameter in your case.

Comment: @Jaylen you're just creating a variable the reference the same list. No copying of the actual data is happening here. Just to clarify that. This has absolutely no significant performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

[`List.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a *predicate*, i.e. a delegate that returns true or false for an item in the list, not an item itself.

You want [`List.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx), which takes an item returning true or false depending on whether it's in the list.

```
var f = allRelations.Where(x => x.CurrentObjectId == 6 
    && !toExclude.Contains(x.RemoteObjectId)).ToList();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yz3vKT) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, if you don't want to use the `Exists` method:

```
var f = allRelations.Where(x => x.CurrentObjectId == 6 
                             && !toExclude.Contains(x.RemoteObjectId))
                    .ToList();
```

On the other hand, you could make use of `Exists`. However, this method expects for a predicate.

```
var f = allRelations.Where(x => x.CurrentObjectId == 6 
                            && !toExclude.Exists(te => te == x.RemoteObjectId))
                    .ToList();
```

For further information on the latter, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var f = allRelations.Where(x => x.CurrentObjectId == 6 
                            && !toExceule.Any(a=>a==x.RemoteObjectId) )
                        .ToList();
```

you can use `.Any()` and this will do a foreach a in toExceule check if a== RemoteObjectId

Answer (score 0):

Following LINQ Query will pull all the list of relations that have current object id equal to 6 and that does not have its remote object id equal to included in toExclude List.

```
var result = relations.Where(r => r.CurrentObjectId == 6 && !toExclude.Any(t => t == r.RemoteObjectId)).ToList();
```